# Angular / Redux --> store.select(s => s.incidents).subscribe((data) => {} is UNDEFINED

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, redux-observable

I'm implementing Redux in Angular, but I've some troubles. I'm struggling to get the data from the redux store in a list in a particular component.ts file.
In     `store.select(s => s.incidentsNew).subscribe((incidents) => { this.incidentsNew = incidents; console.log(incidents); });` are this.incidentsNew & incidents `undefined`

Here is my sample code:

**incidentlist.component.ts:**

```
export class IncidentlistComponent implements OnInit {
  incidentsNew: Incident[];

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private incidentService: IncidentService,
    private store: Store<AppState>
  ) {
    store.select(s => s.incidentsNew).subscribe((incidents) => {
      this.incidentsNew = incidents;
      console.log(incidents);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadData();
  }

  loadData(): void {
    this.incidentService.loadNewIncidents();
    console.log(this.incidentsNew);
  }

}
```

**app.state.ts**

```
export interface AppState {
  readonly incidentsNew: Incident[];
}
```

**incident.reducer.ts**

```
export function incidentReducer(state: Incident[] = [initialState], action: IncidentActions.Actions): Incident[] {
  switch (action.type) {
    case IncidentActions.SET_INCIDENT:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**incident.actions.ts**

```
export const ADD_INCIDENT = '[INCIDENT] Add';
export const REMOVE_INCIDENT = '[INCIDENT] Remove';

export const SET_INCIDENTS = '[INCIDENT] Set';

export class AddIncident implements Action {
  readonly type = ADD_INCIDENT;

  constructor(public payload: Incident) {}
}

export class RemoveIncident implements Action {
  readonly type = REMOVE_INCIDENT;

  constructor(public payload: number) {}
}

export class SetIncidents implements Action {
  readonly type = SET_INCIDENTS;
  constructor(public payload: Incident[]) {}
}

export type Actions = AddIncident | RemoveIncident | SetIncidents;
```

**incident.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class IncidentService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private store: Store<AppState>) {
  }

  loadNewIncidents(): void{
    this.http.get<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/incident/REGISTERED`).subscribe((data) => {
      this.store.dispatch(new IncidentActions.SetIncidents(data));
    });
  }
}
```

In the Redux Devtools I see it's filled with the correct data. Still there is something going wrong
Anybody some thoughts?

UPDATE:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should create a selector for `incidentsNew` https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors. Can we see your structure in Redux Devtools?

Comment: I added pictures of the redux store. Did you meant this with the structure? I also tried with a selector but didn't work. @AliF50

Comment: Not the action payload but the structure of the store. I think it should be the state tab.

Comment: A good way to debug it would be to do `this.store.select(s => s).subcribe(s => console.log(s));`. Look at the log and see the structure of you store and then change the selector accordingly. Better yet, make a selector function.

Comment: Found the solution. In my app.state.ts file the variable was named `incidentsNew`.
I had to change it to incident because it has to match to the model I declared. Thanks for the valuable information about selectors, also helped me a lot @AliF50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. In my app.state.ts file the variable was named `incidentsNew`.
I had to change it to `incident` because it has to match to the model I declared.